# Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, dependencyobject

I'm working on a custom login `Textbox` that has an `Auto Complete` function. However, When i try to:

```
public static void SetSelectOnMouseOver(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ListBoxItemBehavior.SelectOnMouseOverProperty, 
            (object)(bool)(value ? 1 : 0));
    }
```

I get an error `(object)(bool)(value ? 1 : 0));` > `cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'`, what's wrong?

Comment: You can not use casting for `int` to `bool`, you have an option to use [`Convert.ToBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean(v=vs.110).aspx) which would **convert 0 to false and for non zero values it will return `true`**. But you can avoid all that and simply use `Value` parameter without any condition. At least that is what it looks like in your code.

Comment: I understand its a silly question, but I see no reason to downvote.

Comment: @Habib No reason that's right but i have got to make it visual to others for hard review or even on paper.

Comment: @Hossam, not really sure how much readable that would be , I mean you are using a bool -> then returning integer values -> then converting it back to bool.

Comment: @Habib ohh about that yes, i just stated down there that it was stupid.. didn't realize that until `David` pointed it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`value` is already a `bool`.  Why not just use `(object) value`, or even just `value`?

Comment: Moreover, since all types in CLR are derived from `System.Object`, it should be simply `value` without explicit cast. Compiler will implicitely cast it, if nessesary.

Comment: I just answered that up there "No reason that's right but i have got to make it visual to others for hard review or even on paper."